# How to format my phone number like xxxx-xxx-xxx using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to format my telephone number like `xxxx-xxx-xxx` using javascript, how can I make it?

Below is the code:

**HTML**

```
<input onkeypress="isInputNumber(event)" type="text"  id="phonenumber" placeholder = "xxxx-xxx-xxxx" maxlength="11"/>
```

**Javascript**

```
function isInputNumber(evt){
    var ch=String.fromCharCode(evt.which);
    if(!(/[0-9]/.test(ch))){
          evt.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: Using inputmask - https://codepen.io/oceaniclife/pen/eqVOwz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById('phonenumber').addEventListener('blur', function (e) {
        var x = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{4})(\d{3})(\d{4})/);
        e.target.value =  x[1] + '-' + x[2] + '-' + x[3];
    });    
function isInputNumber(evt){
        var ch=String.fromCharCode(evt.which);
        if(!(/[0-9]/.test(ch))){
            evt.preventDefault();
        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input onkeypress="isInputNumber(event)" type="text"  id="phonenumber" placeholder = "xxxx-xxx-xxxx" maxlength="11"/>
```

Try This

Comment: May I ask why you are requiring jQuery ?

Comment: This solution simply errors when the input field is partly filled, and jQuery is not needed.